# New version of keras causes shape mismatch

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

The following code works fine under tensorflow 2.3.1, but under 2.4.0 a shape mismatch occurs between obs_last and obs_now while attempting to train the inverse model(it's an icm neural net). In the previous version of tensorflow the inverse model would expect a nonetype shape IE. (None,None,1) but now it is expecting a specific shape IE. (None,12,1) Does anyone know of a change with the recurent nets that may have caused this to occur.
The error: https://hastebin.com/uyizanabay.yaml

```
from keras.layers import Input, Concatenate, GRU, Dense, Reshape
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.backend import clear_session
from pathlib import Path
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT, TimeoutExpired
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from rl.agents import SARSAAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
import os

cmd = 'echo Hello World!'
env_reward = 0
length_penalty = .25
learning_reward = 10

hidden_layers = 4
layer_neurons = 128
learning_rate = 0.001
nb_actions = 96

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')

done = False
cmd_in = True
obs_last = None
initialize = True

while True:
    if cmd_in:
        proc = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
        try:
            stdout = proc.communicate(timeout=1)[0].decode()
            exitcode = proc.returncode
        except TimeoutExpired:
            proc.kill()
            stdout = proc.communicate()[0].decode()
            exitcode = proc.returncode
        nnin = ''.join(char for char in stdout if char.isprintable())
        filename = Path('mem.txt')
        filename.touch(exist_ok=True)
        if not nnin:
            nnin = 'Done!'
            stdout = nnin
        if exitcode == 0:
            done = True
            with open('mem.txt', 'r+') as mem:
                for line in stdout.splitlines():
                    if line + '\n' not in mem:
                        mem.write(line + '\n')
                        env_reward += learning_reward
        cmd = ''
        print('\n')
        print(stdout)
        print('# ', end='', flush=True)
    else:
        nnin = cmd
        print(nnin[-1], end='', flush=True)
    idxs = np.frombuffer(nnin.encode(), dtype=np.uint8) - 32
    env = tf.one_hot(idxs, 95)
    shape = env.shape
    env_reward -= length_penalty


    def build_actor_model(shape, nb_actions):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Reshape(shape[1::], input_shape=shape))
        for layer in range(hidden_layers):
            model.add(GRU(layer_neurons, name='GRU' + str(layer), return_sequences=True))
        model.add(GRU(layer_neurons, name='GRU' + str(hidden_layers)))
        model.add(Dense(nb_actions, name='output', activation='softmax'))
        return model


    def build_main(shape, name_prefix='main.'):
        inputs = Input(shape=shape)
        x = inputs
        for layer in range(hidden_layers):
            x = GRU(layer_neurons, name=name_prefix + ('GRU' + str(layer)), return_sequences=True)(x)
        x = GRU(layer_neurons, name=name_prefix + ('GRU' + str(hidden_layers)))(x)
        model = Model(inputs, x, name=name_prefix + 'main')
        return model


    def build_inverse_model(obs1, obs2, nb_actions):
        x = Concatenate()([obs1.output, obs2.output])
        x = Dense(nb_actions, name='icm_i.output', activation='sigmoid')(x)
        i_model = Model([obs1.input, obs2.input], x, name='icm_inverse_model')
        return i_model


    def build_forward_model(obs1, nb_actions):
        act1 = Input(shape=nb_actions)
        x = Concatenate()([obs1.output, act1])
        output_shape = obs1.output_shape[1]
        x = Dense(output_shape, name='icm_f.output', activation='linear')(x)
        f_model = Model([obs1.input, act1], x, name='icm_forward_model')
        return f_model


    inv_weights_fname = '{}_inv_weights.h5f'.format("SMB")
    fwd_weights_fname = '{}_fwd_weights.h5f'.format("SMB")
    agent_weights_fname = '{}_agent_weights.h5f'.format("SMB")

    main = build_main(shape)
    main2 = build_main(shape, name_prefix='main2.')
    inverse_model = build_inverse_model(main, main2, nb_actions)
    inverse_model.compile(Adam(learning_rate), loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])
    forward_model = build_forward_model(main, nb_actions)
    forward_model.compile(Adam(learning_rate), loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])
    model = build_actor_model((1,) + shape, nb_actions)
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    agent = SARSAAgent(model=model, nb_actions=nb_actions, policy=policy)
    agent.compile(Adam(learning_rate), metrics=['mae'])
    agent.reset_states()

    if initialize:
        if os.path.isfile(inv_weights_fname):
            inverse_model.load_weights(inv_weights_fname)
        if os.path.isfile(fwd_weights_fname):
            forward_model.load_weights(fwd_weights_fname)
        if os.path.isfile(agent_weights_fname):
            agent.load_weights(agent_weights_fname)
        initialize = False
    agent.training = True
    
    obs_now = env
    if obs_last is None:
        obs_last = obs_now
    action = agent.forward(obs_now)
    icm_action = np.zeros(nb_actions)
    icm_action[action] = 1
    inv_loss = inverse_model.train_on_batch([np.expand_dims(obs_last, 0), np.expand_dims(obs_now, 0)],
                                            [np.expand_dims(icm_action, 0)])
    features_now = main.predict(np.expand_dims(obs_now, 0))
    fwd_loss = forward_model.train_on_batch([np.expand_dims(obs_last, 0), np.expand_dims(icm_action, 0)],
                                            [features_now])
    obs_last = obs_now
    r_intr = (fwd_loss[0] ** 0.5) / 100
    reward = r_intr + env_reward
    agent.backward(reward, done)
    clear_session()
    done = False

    enc_ascii = action + 32
    if enc_ascii != 127:
        cmd += chr(enc_ascii)
        cmd_in = False
        continue
    cmd_in = True
    inverse_model.save_weights(inv_weights_fname, overwrite=True)
    forward_model.save_weights(fwd_weights_fname, overwrite=True)
    agent.save_weights(agent_weights_fname, overwrite=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Contacted tensorflow development team, and it appears to be a bug. I found a work around, but I am not going to implement it unless it ends up being a won't fix situation. For reference the work around is to pad the inputs to the same length, but this shouldn't be necessary